# CSS button not styling

Tags: asp.net, css, button

I must be missing something obvious, but can someone explain what I'm doing wrong with my CSS? I would like all buttons to have a certain format, except a few. I was expecting to use `CssClass` in order to override the few that should be different, but they all seem to use the standard one.

My CSS:

```
.btn
{       
     border:none;
     background-color:red;         
}    

input[type="submit"]
{
     border: 2px solid black;
     background-color:green;        
}
```

All the buttons take the second value (green background, with a border). However, I have this button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" CssClass="btn" runat="server" Text="Add" />
```

I was expecting this to have no border, and a red background, but it's the same as every other button.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML code instead of the ASP source? What browser(s) are you trying this in?

Comment: Isn't the CSS border attribute ordered style width color not width style color? border:[style] [width] [color]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type='button'` rule probably beats the `btn` rule in specificity. You could use `!important` but that won't work in IE < 8 and is bound to give problems in the long run.

Try this first:

```
input[type="submit"].btn
    {

         border:none;
         background-color:red;

    }
```

Comment: That works. I'll use this method instead, for compatibility. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Place your `.btn` below you `input[type="submit"]` rule. If that still does not work add !important.

```
.btn
{    
     border:none !important;
     background-color:red !important;    
}
```

See here for CSS precedence: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting that attribute selectors such as `input[type="submit"]` won't work in IE, they do in FF though.

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to be working in IE8 for me. Is there an alternative way of styling all buttons in for IE?

Comment: I meant IE 6,7 - 8 may well support them but definitely the older version do not. There's no CSS-only way of selecting elements by their attributes in these browsers, you could always apply `class="submit"` to all submit buttons and then apply style to `.submit` however.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I'll create a submit class and use that then.