# Why does my CSS style not update my control when I change it?

Tags: asp.net, css, button

I have a CSS style at the top of my page that styles my buttons.
But when I change the color (or any propert) it doesn't update my button. 
To fix this, I have to Change the name of my style and every where in my project where it's referenced, then only does it update the change of the style.

Why does this happen?

My style (for example - Basic style I know)

```
  .CSSButtonStyle {
      background: #FFFFFF;
        }
```

My button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="CSSButtonStyle" runat="server" Text="Update/Submit" Width="150" Height="30" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

In my design view, the button is white, but on the website its still blue or whatever previous color I had in my style

What I've tried

[image]

Comment: Can you actually view source of the css to ensure its changed? Definetly sounds like caching

Comment: design view is not reliable. have you tried !important to make sure it's not getting overruled?

Comment: Stupid question, but you _are_ using IE to browse, no? Other browsers don't obey IE's Delete Browsing History command (and vice versa).

Comment: !important? No, havent tried that.
and yes I am using IE.
and the CSS class is showing background: #FFFFFF; while it runs...

Comment: please see on this link

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568569/css-button-not-styling

Comment: @DiederikEEn Your solution of adding !important worked. Pleas add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `!important` to the css. This makes sure it wont get overuled by any other css

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to press `Ctrl + F5` to reload the page instead of just `F5`. It forces a cache refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
input[type="submit"].CSSButtonStyle
    {

         border:none;
         background-color:#FFFFFF;

    }
```